# Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 50, found 51. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am getting below issue, I think it is due to when i restored Db on  my new MYSQL DB 8 from previous MYSQL DB, i took backup of all db and restored that all db into new MYSQL 8, which may have corrupted  my new MYSQL 8 DB schema and after that i am getting below issue :-
Current Mysql version - mysql 8

**T05:54:58.457447Z 999167 [ERROR] [MY-013143] [Server] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 50, found 51. The table is probably corrupted**

It would be very helpful if anyone can give prompt suggestion or solution. I tried most of things provided in stack overflow (like mysql upgarde, skipping external lock etc ) already but it did  not works.